# Xcode - multiple URL Schemes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, url-scheme

In my app I want to have two Different URL Schemes.
Like **One** and **Two**
So the user can open my app with:
`one://something`
and
`two://something`

I am using this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
}
```

How will the app know if the user types one or two?

Answer (score 11):

`handleOpenURL` is deprecated, so if you're targeting iOS 4.2 or later, you should instead use [`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)

In both cases, you will be passed an [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html), on which you can just access [the `scheme` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/scheme) to find out what scheme was used to access your app.

EDIT: For readability; in your implementation of `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, the code would be something similar to;

```
if([[url scheme] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"one"] == NSOrderedSame) 
{ 
    /* one here */ 
} else { 
    /* not one here */ 
}
```

Comment: so my code will looks like this ? : - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url { i dont know, exactly how should i use the application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Comment: @JonathanGurebo Something like; `if(![[url scheme] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"one"]) { /* one here */ } else { /* not one here */ }`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You should edit your answer with that code so it is easier to read.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, added the code to the answer for readability.

Comment: Since `caseInsensitiveCompare:` returns an enum value, you should change that to `if ([[url scheme] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"one"] == NSOrderedSame)`.

Comment: @rmaddy `NSOrderedSame` equals `0`, so a `!` is equivalent. For readability you're right though that it's cleaner.

Comment: I know it is equal to zero. But it's an enum. Code shouldn't rely on an enum having a specific numerical value. The code is safer and more readable if you use the actual defined enum names.