# What is use of FBSDKApplicationDelegate during Facebook Login?

Tags: swift, facebook, delegates

In AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }



    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

     return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

 func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()


    }
```

Even I am not using these methods,Login is working fine
and in my logout method

```
FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
        FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)
        loginView.logOut()
```

Then what is use of these methods in AppDelegate class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` post process the results from Facebook Login or Facebook Dialogs (or any action that requires switching over to the native Facebook app or Safari). More explaination could be found on [official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKApplicationDelegate/)

Comment: Can you please this URL ..it is saying somewhat different

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226240/handling-different-url-schemes-in-ios-facebook-and-instagram